# Feelings on Seasonal Hats

Tags: discussion

It’s time for Winter Bash 2016!!

**Overview**

Those of you who are on other Stack Exchange sites may remember previous years’ events, but here is a quick little reminder. Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users have fun by earning “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (very similar to badges). We track everyone’s progress using hats in a leaderboard.

**The Details**

The event will run from 19 December 2016 up to and including 08 January 2017. Users will be able to see all the hats they’ve earned on http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an *“I hate hats”* option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

**Discussion**

I am open to hearing the thoughts of the Korean.SE community on if we want to participate in Winter Bash. I have participated in Winter Bash on a few other Stack Exchange sites before and enjoyed it.

We have the option of opting out of participating in Hats for Korean.SE if there is a majority desire to stay out of the Winter Bash fun.

Please discuss any feelings you have on Winter Bash (yea/nay, etc.)

Comment: I love hats, I'm in.

Answer (score 3):

I guess if you like hats, it's good, and if not, you get to press a button that says 'I hate hats'... so I don't see why not!

Answer (score 3):

Individual users have the choice of opting out so it should be ok to allow hats on our stack exchange